# How to remove init by using dynatable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynatable

im using the current version of dynatable, see:
http://www.dynatable.com/

in the desktop-version the page is laoding and the script should be init - works.
by resizing the browser, this init must be deactive < 600px width. but i dont now how to.

is there a generel JS way / jQuery to remove a special init?